# Combining two Pokémon. Is it possible?

Tags: pokemon-go

Can two Pokémon of the same species and same CP but different abilities be combined together? I think this would be a great way to make more powerful Pokémon. For example, two Paras, one has the skills Scratch and X-Scissors whereas the other has Scratch and Seed Bomb. Both are of different height and weights though.

Comment: Breeding has been mentioned as a feature that might be added to the game, but currently no.

Answer (score 1):

No it is not possible to combine Pokemon in this way. You can only power Pokemon through using candy.